# Using HTML in PHP If Statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a PHP file in Wordpress that has some HTML, "Login & Register" that I would only like to show when a member of the site is not logged in. When they are logged in I would like it to show "Welcome, [name]."

I'm just not sure how to use HTML in a PHP If statement. The condition is this:

```
<?php
      if ( member_is_logged_in() ) {
         print "Welcome [name]";
      } else {
         print "<a href="...">Login</a> | <a href="...">Register</a>";
      }
?>
```

That's how I think it should look, but it's not working. I'm not that great with PHP, but I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: how is it not working, no output? not detecting logged in state ?

Comment: Well Sacheleen and Gordan provided excelent answers.. another solution is your choice of quotes. If you wrap your string in double quotes and have a double quote in the string, you break your string, so you can escape it by add a `\` before it like `\"` and this logic also applies to single quotes.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help! I got it figured out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHP variables in double quoted strings. so just replace [name] with $name or whatever the variable is. Note this will *not* work with single quotes.

Also, you have two sets of double quotes in the else case. This will result in a syntax error. Make one of them single quotes or escape the inside quotes.

```
<?php
      if ( member_is_logged_in() ) {
         print "Welcome $name";
      } else {
         print '<a href="...">Login</a> | <a href="...">Register</a>';
      }
?>
```

You can also just end the PHP tag and write the HTML directly.

```
<?php
      if ( member_is_logged_in() ) {
         print "Welcome $name";
      } else {
?>
         <a href="...">Login</a> | <a href="...">Register</a>
<?php
      }
?>
```

There exists a better and easier to read syntax for this:

```
<?php if(<your evaluation here>): ?>
HTML for when true
<?php else: ?>
HTML for when false
<?php endif; ?>
```

Check out [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for more information on this.

And while we're at it, [print vs echo, which one is faster?](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/8/print-vs-echo-which-one-is-faster)

Comment: I know this is a matter of preference, but I find mixed PHP and HTML in the way you describe in the "better" syntax harder to read. That 2nd syntax is just horrible - not just mixed PHP-and-HTML but mixed PHP and mixed-PHP-and-HTML.

Comment: Just presenting the available options. :) Personally, I kind of like option 3, but I agree that 2 sucks.

Answer (score 1):

simply:

```
<?php
      if ( member_is_logged_in() ) {
         print "Welcome $name";
      } else { ?>
         <a href="...">Login</a> | <a href="...">Register</a>
      <?php }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use wordpress try below code:

See Utl:- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user

E.g.: To determine if there is a user currently logged in, do this:

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
    // Not logged in.
} else {
    // Logged in.
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code chunk and let me know---

```
<?php
      if ( member_is_logged_in() ) {
    global $display_name;
    get_currentuserinfo();
         print "Welcome ".$display_name;
      } else {
         print "<a href="...">Login</a> | <a href="...">Register</a>";
      }
?>
```